# Jquery mobile popup content appearing during page load

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I'm using Jquery Mobile in my website, and I have a page with popups. I don't directly navigate to this page, but I inject the content with Ajax :

```
$("#myDiv").html(data).enhanceWithin();
```

The problem is that occasionally, when the page is loading, the popups content appear for half a second on the screen and then disappear...

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: If the page isn't visited yet, don't use `.enhanceWithin()`, the page will be created with all elements within upon visiting it for the first time.

Comment: Without it, the buttons don't have the Jquery Mobile style...

Comment: please add more details. When do you add contents by Ajax? When do you see the popups?